# UITableView background view on iOS 4

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, uitableview

guys, I have UITableView and image, which should be background.
My code:

```
[self.tableView setBackgroundView:[[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BG.png"]] autorelease]];
```

On iOS 5 it works perfect, but on iOS 4 I've found something strange.

Video:
http://cl.ly/FHbj

PS: I'm using custom UITableView from github.com: https://github.com/zadr/PullToRefresh/tree/502cda2e3bf7eb9f39dc3c93cfd1aaa3a02a2ce7

Answer (score 1):

Hey just set the background of tableview in interface builder to clear color and place the image back to the tableview